# npm local development vs production package versions

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I am trying to use my own package (let's call it database) in a project of mine.
However since I am developing database next to the project myself, I don't want to push a version of database to the registry, then pull again on the project to have the latest version. This is not a fast workflow given that both projects are in the same VS workspace.

What I need is to reference the local project while development and when it is about production, then I need to actually use an external package. Is there a way that allows me to use a different package version of the same package depending on the environment?

I wish there was a NodeJS / Typescript IDE that just manages packages, building dependencies etc. for me. E.g when I build my project, it would build database first. I know there are project references in typescript 3.0, however I am not sure how well they work with npm packages.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your package `database` directory
and run `npm link` to create a global symlink, it would be like you have installed the `database` globally.

Go to your project to run `npm link database` to use the local global package.

You don't need to update your project's dependency when you update the `database` since the global package is just a local symbol link to your `database`.

When you are ready to go production, run `npm unlink database` to remove the local symbol link, and reinstall the package from the registry for the project, you need to publish it first of course.